# How do I view a "Scheduled and Sent" mailing without creating a draft?

Tags: civimail

Is there a way to view "Scheduled and Sent" mailings in CiviCRM other than clicking the Re-Use button? This creates a draft of the email which our users sometimes forget to delete, and it's caused some confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go to the Report for that Mailing (via Scheduled and Sent Mailings), then there should be a link on that page to HTML Message - view complete message